# How to draw 3D curves by SciPy?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

I draw a 2D curve with the code

```
c = 11
x = np.arange(0, 5, 0.1)
y = np.exp(c)/x
plt.plot(x,y)
```

How can I draw a series of the `x,y` curves while the z axis is `c`? The first line will be changed to

```
c = np.arange(1, 70, 1)
```

How can I draw the 70 `x,y` curves along the `z` axis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use matplotlibs `Axes3D`, a tutorial can be found [here](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

c = np.arange(1, 10, 1) # made this 10 so that the graph is more readable
x = np.arange(0, 5, 0.1)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

for i in c:
    y = np.exp(i) / x
    ax.plot(x, y, i)

    ax.set_xlabel("x")
    ax.set_ylabel("y")
    ax.set_zlabel("z")

plt.show()
```

Which gives the figure:

[image]